# How do I create a Magento extension package that works in both 1.4 and 1.5?

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.4

I am having a hell of a time getting my extension up on Magento Connect. My first attempt I released as Beta, and on version 1.5 I was getting an error "Version number could not be found" when attempting to install. However, this package worked on Magento 1.4 (Magento Connect Manager version 1.0). So I repackaged, uploaded again - this time as Stable - and now the package works fine on Magento Connect 2.0 in Magento 1.5, but Magento Connect 1.0 can't find the package and therefore can't install it. All packages have been created in the Package Extensions tool of a Magento 1.5 install.

Also, is there a way to remove or overwrite uploaded extension packages or do I need to increment the version number with each upload?

Comment: Get in touch with Rhonda, http://twitter.com/#!/rondata, Connect's in the middle of a giant overhaul and she's herding everyone towards the eventual goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to upload your package twice, first use the package output in /var/pear and then change the version, repackage and upload the one in /var/connect.

Comment: I've been having similar trouble. Which version number are you changing? Is it just the Connect version (1.0 to 2.0) or the module's own number too?

Comment: I was chaning the module version number as well because Magento Connect wouldn't let me upload the same package filename twice. Per Alan's comment above I've been in contact with @rondata on twitter and email. She just wrote a blog post about this. This was working, but apparently you can simply package your module and only select 'Pre-1.5.0.0' and DO NOT select '1.5.0.0 & After'. Then you upload the package found in /var/pear and Magento Connect will automatically create a version for Magento Connect 2.0 for you. This worked for me.